# My update on sqlite not persistent (after changing page)

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I was working on this app from a tutorial and I got everything to work, but the part where the update stays persistent The ListTile items update when I press the button to update (onTap), but they change their values to original ones after I leave the page. Here is my code for update:

```
Future<int> update(Food food) async {
final db = await database;

return await db.update(
  TABLE_FOOD,
  food.toMap(),
  where: "id = ?",
  whereArgs: [food.id],
);
```

}

```
class UpdateFood extends FoodEvent {
  Food newFood;
  int foodIndex;

  UpdateFood(int index, Food food) {
    newFood = food;
    foodIndex = index;
  }
}
```

The update button updates the values of the ListTile items, but they do not stay persistent, they return to original values after I change the page and then return to the main one.

Here is the init state, maybe something is wrong with it:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseProvider.db.getFoods().then(
      (foodList) {
        BlocProvider.of<FoodBloc>(context).add(SetFoods(foodList));
      },
```

I understand if the issue is not in one of these, but maybe a setState or initState, so here is a full Github code, it is a very short app, and it would probably take just a few minutes for someone to tell what the issue is:

https://github.com/cheetahcoding/CwC_Flutter/tree/sqflite_tutorial/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss to update the updated `Food` object into DB in `food_form.dart`

```
// This one is the updated one, 
Food food = Food(
  id: widget.food.id, // add this line
  name: _name,
  calories: _calories,
  isVegan: _isVegan,
);

DatabaseProvider.db.update(food).then(    // <= change "widget.food" to "food"
  (storedFood) => BlocProvider.of<FoodBloc>(context).add(
  UpdateFood(widget.foodIndex, food),
  ),
);
```

the DB update transaction is success but the values are the old one.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, I knew that the issue was there, but after thousands of lines, I couldn't figure it out. Kudos!

Comment: You welcome! You can get familiar with debug mode and split a action into many steps. It can help debugging.